# Simple IAP with Urban Airship

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com, in-app-purchase

I'm building an app that uses Urban Airship to deliver IAPs.  Have used them before and it has worked great, but I just bolted on their on UI that time.

This time I would like to go from our own TableView to a DetailView where the user can buy the product.  This without going back to UA's StoreFront and showing the content in the store.  I've tried to go thru the UA files, but get totally lost.

Anyone that can give me a hand?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just done this for my app.

The simplest approach is to start with their `UAProductDetailViewController` and the associated xib and graphics from their StoreFrontUI example.

Then, you can get the list of all the products by calling:

```
[UAStoreFront productsForType:ProductTypeAll];
```

From your table controller, you can open the detail view for one of those products:

```
UAProductDetailViewController *controller = [[UAProductDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UAProductDetail" bundle:nil];
[controller setProduct:product];
```

That should display the detail view, and you can play with the XIB and get it looking how you want it to.

Personally, I turned the price label into a buy button, grabbed the "buy now" handling from their `UAStoreFrontViewController`, and added that to the details view along with the progress bar etc.

Tim

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried to send my productID, which is a string, in the setProduct but it crashes the app.  What do I need to send there?  Also have you any code to show me how you did the price button and progress bar?

Comment: Anyway I can send the Product ID to the UAProductDetail?  Our tableview isn't loaded from the UA list of products.

Comment: You don't sent the product ID string to setProduct, you must send a UAProduct.  These are returned by the call to [UAStoreFront productsForType:ProductTypeAll]. You can always find the one you're looking for in that list by searching for it (via the product.productIdentifier accessor).

Comment: Still totally stuck.  When I call [UAStoreFront productsForType:ProductTypeAll] - where does it end up? How can I search it and give it to 'product'?

Comment: [UAStoreFront productsForType:ProductTypeAll] returns an NSArray of UAProducts.  Iterate through them looking for the one that matches the ID you're looking for.

Comment: Oh, and downloading the source for the UA library itself is vital, since they don't have any other useful documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I will battle on with this somehow. I have UA incorporated in the project.  Just need a way to get directly to the DetailView bypassing their tableview.

Comment: Tried  NSArray *listOfProducts = [UAStoreFront productsForType:ProductTypeAll]; But that ended up empty.

Comment: Any chance you could show me how you did the download progress and price button? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @tarmes Can you help me with IAP. I have set up all the things at both ends i.e iTunesConnect as well Urban Airship.Everything works well in simulator other than payment, but when testing the IAP for Payment, the Paid Product doesn't get listed in iPhone though they showup in Simulator.What would be the reasons, as if I have already verified Keys as well as the ProductID.But the application does't list down the Paid content in the UAStore.Please help me or give me some clues , I really got stuck on this.